# Bizdays is returning the wrong date. Is my calendar broken?

Tags: r, calendar, bizdays

I'm trying to get previous business days (and previous previous business days) using the bizdays package so that I can use it later. However for some reason the two objects I want to create seem to only returning today's date nomatter what function I use.

The code is below:

```
yr_plus_1 <- lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) + 1
    holidays <- lubridate::ymd(timeDate::holidayLONDON(2019:yr_plus_1))
    cal <- create.calendar(name = "MyCalendar", holidays = holidayLONDON(), weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"), financial = FALSE)
    ## Get prev business day(s)
    prev_buisness_day <- modified.preceding(as.Date(Sys.time()), "MyCalendar")
    prev_prev_businesss_day <- modified.preceding(prev_buisness_day, cal)
```

Could it be my calendar is going wrong? Any advice is greatly appreciated.